# How Faster RCNN library load training dataset for training?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I use [Faster RCNN library](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) for Deep Learning and here is a [discussion](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/issues/243) of how to train own dataset. That is one step ahead of me.

For me I like to understand how dataset for training is setup and how it is loaded for training?

When I look at the code, I saw this line of code

`imdb = get_imdb(imdb_name)` from `train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py` and it calls `factory.py inside datasets folder`.

factory.py has

```
for year in ['2007', '2012']:
    for split in ['train', 'val', 'trainval', 'test']:
        name = 'voc_{}_{}'.format(year, split)
        __sets[name] = (lambda split=split, year=year: pascal_voc(split, year))

# Set up coco_2014_<split>
for year in ['2014']:
    for split in ['train', 'val', 'minival', 'valminusminival']:
        name = 'coco_{}_{}'.format(year, split)
        __sets[name] = (lambda split=split, year=year: coco(split, year))

# Set up coco_2015_<split>
for year in ['2015']:
    for split in ['test', 'test-dev']:
        name = 'coco_{}_{}'.format(year, split)
        __sets[name] = (lambda split=split, year=year: coco(split, year))

def get_imdb(name):
    """Get an imdb (image database) by name."""
    if not __sets.has_key(name):
        raise KeyError('Unknown dataset: {}'.format(name))
    return __sets[name]()

def list_imdbs():
    """List all registered imdbs."""
    return __sets.keys()
```

I am wondering how training data for this imdb name `voc_2007_trainval` is loaded for training?

EDIT:
When I print `__sets[name]() inside def get_imdb(name):`, I see the following.

```
p __sets[name]()
<datasets.pascal_voc.pascal_voc object at 0x7fc937383ed0>
```

What does that mean?

Comment: look at `datasets/pascal_voc.py` in class `pascal_voc`.

Comment: @Thanks Shai, i found the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understood.
lib/datasets/factory.py has

```
def get_imdb(name):
    """Get an imdb (image database) by name."""
    if not __sets.has_key(name):
        raise KeyError('Unknown dataset: {}'.format(name))
    return __sets[name]()
```

__sets[name] calls

```
for year in ['2007', '2012']:
    for split in ['train', 'val', 'trainval', 'test']:
        name = 'voc_{}_{}'.format(year, split)
        __sets[name] = (lambda split=split, year=year: pascal_voc(split, year))
```

Since we set `--imdb voc_2007_trainval` in the training command, what it does is that the program can load the images stated inside trainval file in `data/VOCdevkit2007/VOC2007/ImageSets/Main/trainval.txt` file.

If we set `--imdb voc_2007_train` then `train.txt` will be used. All images are inside JPEGImages folder and annotations are in Annotations folder.